# Calculate/subtract the difference between two date time columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, subtraction

How can we calculate the difference between two date time columns in Python Pandas? Below is the sample table:

| starttime | endtime |
| --- | --- |
| 06:10:42 AM | 06:20:00 AM |
| 03:45:54 AM | 03:52:27 AM |

Desired result:

| starttime | endtime | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06:10:42 AM | 06:20:00 AM | 0:10:00 |
| 03:45:54 AM | 03:52:27 AM | 0:06:33 |

I tried this script. However, it returns an error:

`df_null['Total'] = (df_null['endtime']).sub(df_null['starttime'])`

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors, post them as code-formatted text.

Comment: Try: `df['total'] = df[['starttime', 'endtime']].apply(pd.to_datetime).diff(axis=1)['endtime'].astype(str).str[-8:]`?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. However, it also returns an error. `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

Comment: @jislesplr. Convert your columns as strings before then as datetime. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['total'] = (df[['starttime', 'endtime']].astype(str)
                   .apply(pd.to_datetime).diff(axis=1)['endtime']
                   .astype(str).str[-8:])
print(df)

# Output
      starttime      endtime     total
0   06:10:42 AM  06:20:00 AM  00:09:18
1   03:45:54 AM  03:52:27 AM  00:06:33
```

In python you can't subtract two `time` objects

```
from datetime import time

start = time(3, 45, 54)
end = time(3, 52, 27)

end - start

...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endtime'])

df['total'] = df['end']-df['start']
```